# Model object properties identification

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

We are using SQLite property database to get information about object's properties. The problem we are facing with is property identification. For each property we have:

- id: looks like it is just an autoincremental id and it can be used to
  identify property between two versions of the same model
- name: for .rvt models it is mostly unique, but there are some duplications
  sometimes (for example the same property with different flags,
  readonly and not); for .ifc files it is not unique at all
- category + displayName: the problem with this
  fields is that after using design automation API (to change and
  re-save model) category/displayName can be translated into English
  (but initially they can be, for example, in German)

Now we are using the combination of 'name + category + displayName' to identify the property, but it is not the solution, because this combination still is not unique in some rare cases (it is data lost for us) and it doesn't solve the problem with property names translation using Design Automation API.

Any ideas how to identify properties will be helpful! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a given element, the `externalId` should be unique within that model (at the model level, the `urn` is unique). There is no unique identification for properties.

I'm interested in understand this workflow better, are you able to have a quick talk? Please [use this link](http://calendly.com/autodeskforge/augustogoncalves) to book a time.